# Call A method in controller from Nlog config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nlog

I need to send an email every time the Nlog config writes into the database. Can i call a method in my controller from Nlog Config?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want your logs to be written to both database and email as log targets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can call static methods from configuration: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/MethodCall-target
2. You can send to an email from configuration: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Mail-target

But since 1 is very clear about it, you need to have a static, public method which your controller isn't